# write a query in elasticsearch, to search a field (IP_address) with custom pattern analyzer and normal full text search?

Tags: elasticsearch

**Check my analyzer**

```
PUT my_index
    {
      "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "my_custom_ip_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "my_tokenizer": {
              "type": "pattern",
              "pattern": "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])",
              "group":0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Check my mapping**
    PUT /my_index/_mapping/reports
    {
        "properties": {
            "IP_address" : {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "my_custom_ip_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }

**Adding some data to my_index**

```
PUT /my_index/reports/5
{
    "document_id": "Doc-4004-05-15",
                    "title": "logical"
                    "email_address": "raj@gmail.com",
                    "IP_address": "192.168.1.1",
                    "rating": "low"
}
PUT /my_index/reports/6
{
    "document_id": "Doc-4006-06-16",
                    "title": "logical"
                    "IP_address": "this is ip 192.168.1.1",
                    "rating": "low"
}
```

**And now if I search**

```
GET /my_index/reports/_search
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "IP_address": "this is ip 192.168.1.1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I get the following output:**

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

but this is not what i am looking for
if i search **"this is ip 192.168.1.1" or "192.168.1.1"** 
in either case i should get 1 result 
so can someone help me with the query?

Comment: Your tokenizer only matches the IP and not any additional text so I wouldn't expect it to be indexed. I may be completely wrong though.

Comment: @apokryfos u r right but i need both the functionality may be using analyzer: keyword

Comment: I would create a second field to index the text normally and then search on both fields.

Comment: can you share the mapping of the index?

Comment: Check my mapping PUT /my_index/_mapping/reports { "properties": { "IP_address" : { "type": "text", "analyzer": "my_custom_ip_analyzer" } } }

Comment: I understand this is what you are PUTting. What comes up when you GET the mapping?